# Tracking who deleted a folder in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, event-viewer, security-policy

Recently there are several cases of missing or deleted files/folder from various shared folders, so we have turned on the audit policy for Delete Subfolders and Files. However there are more than 100 users and many objects are accessed and modified everyday. There are hundreds of audit log entry everyday.

When someone reported a missing folder e.g. FolderABC, how to search the log involving this object only? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can't you just filter the Event Viewer entries using the folder name as a search criteria?

Comment: @user It's always a hard problem when you have too many hands in your pot...
Anyway, have you reviewed the current permissions?
Also, have you tried some folder monitoring utility? this way you could at list know when it happened.